# Sorting list based on variable type - python

Tags: python, list

I am simply trying to sort a list which has both str and int, and remove all the str to just leave an integer list. Here is my code:

list = [22, "Good", "Bye", 1, 7]

for l in list:
    if type(l) == str:
        list.remove(l)
print(list)

I get this in the console:
[22, 'Bye', 1, 7]

It only removes the "Good".
Can someone tell me why it doesn't remove the "Bye"?
Using python 3.4 btw

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you are deleting when iterating
I recommend to use list expressions to create a new list with desired filter

```
>>> a_list = [22, "Good", "Bye", 1, 7]
>>> a_list = [l for l in a_list if type(l) != str]
>>> 
>>> a_list
[22, 1, 7]
```

Comment: Might as well suggest not to use `list` as a variable name

Comment: @shaktimaan You're right, changed!